# How can I diferentiate for example hello1 from hello11?

Tags: java, regex

I'm programming in java and I need to replace certain key words in a `String`.

Imagine that my String is `"Int hello1 \n Int hello11"` and I want to replace `"hello1"` for `"a"` and `"hello11"` for `"b"`.

The problem is when I say `String.replaceAll("hello1", "a");` the original String stays like this: `Int a \n Int a1`, how can I prevent to replace the `hello11`?

What regex should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use word boundaries for this.

You also need to assign the `String` created by the `replaceAll` invocation to another variable as Java `String`s are immutable.

In this example, I'm just printing it through the standard output stream.

```
String input = "Int hello1 \n Int hello11";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\\bhello1\\b", "a"));
```

**Output**

```
Int a 
 Int hello11
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use word boundary in your regex:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("\\bhello1\\b", "a");
repl = str.replaceAll("\\bhello11\\b", "b");
```

Answer (score 0):

Java String Objects are immutable, so you can't alter them.

Reassign the returned value from `replaceAll()` method to that variable.

```
String str = "Int hello1 \n Int hello11";
String yourStr = str.replaceAll("\\bhello1\\", "a");
```

You can even re-assign the returned value like below.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\bhello1\\", "a");
```

Comment: @sheepCow, example added

Comment: okay, and yourStr takes value: "Int a \n Int a1", and I don't want that, I want it to be assigned like this: "Int a \n Int hello11"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `String`, use `StringBuilder`

`StringBuilder`s are mutable and can be altered, so  `replaceAll` will alter all the characters in your string.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility if your string is this targeted is to use a simple negation:

```
String original = "Int hello1 \n Int hello11";
String altered = original.replaceAll("hello1[^1]", "a");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "Int hello1 \n Int hello11";
String replace = input.replace("hello11", "b");
String replace2 = replace.replace("hello1", "a");
System.out.println(replace2);
```

output

Int a
 Int b